# How to ignore an exception from FindElement()?

Tags: c#, webdriver

```
IWebDriver driver;
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Url = "https://upbit.com/exchange?";
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(6)>a")).Click(); //table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(6)>a -> cancel button(hide element)
```

The program executed FindElement and then an exception was thrown and an error window opened.
I want to ignore the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your code with try-catch

```
try
{
IWebDriver driver;
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.Url = "https://upbit.com/exchange?";
 driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(6)>a")).Click(); //table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(6)>a -> cancel button(hide element)
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: Explain more specifically what you want. With this code, your project keep will going to run and ignore exception